# Why isn't this working?

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to take the data from a webform submission and create 2 nodes. I've looked at various examples, but I cannot figure out why this isn't working. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

My file structure looks like:

srs
srs_webform.info.yml
srs_webform.module
src
Plugin
WebformHandler
SRS_WebformHandler.php

```
//srs_webform.info.yml
name: SRS Webform
type: module
description: Create Nodes on webform submission.
package: SRS
core_version_requirement: ^9 || ^10
dependencies:
  - webform:webform
```

```
function srs_webform_theme() {
  return [
    'webform_handler_srs_webform_summary' => [
      'variables' => [
        'settings' => NULL,
        'handler' => [],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

````
//SRS_WebformHandler.php

namespace Drupal\srs_webform\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Serialization\Yaml;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\webform\WebformInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\webformSubmissionInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission;


/**
 * Create a new node entity from a webform submission.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "Create a node",
 *   label = @Translation("Create a node"),
 *   category = @Translation("Entity Creation"),
 *   description = @Translation("Creates a new node from Webform Submissions."),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 *   submission = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::SUBMISSION_REQUIRED,
 * )
 */

class SRS_WebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

  // Create node object from webform-submission.

  // Function to be fired while submitting the Webform.
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    // Get an array of the values from the submission.
    $form_title = $webform->label();
    //if ($form_title = "Enquiry"){
      $values = $webform_submission->getData();

      // First create a Person node
        $node = Node::create([
         'type' => 'person',
         // Use this format: 'node_machine_name_field' => $values('webform_machine_name_field') for below fields.
          'field_firstname' => $values['first_name'],
          'field_surname' => $values['surname'],
          'field_email_address' => $values['email_address'],
          'title' => $values['surname'].", ".$values['first_name']
        ]);
      // Save the Person node
      $node->save();
        // Store the nid of the just saved Person node
        $person_id = $node->nid;

      // Now create the Enquiry node
      $node = Node::create([
        'type' => 'enquiry',
        'field_lead_type' => $values['enquiry_type'],
        'field_query' => $values['query'],
        'field_course' => $values['course'],
        'field_person' => $person_id,
        'title' => $values['surname'].", ".$values['first_name']." - ".$values['enquiry_type']
      ]);
      // Save the Enquiry node
      $node->save();
  }
}```
````

Comment: The question does not say in what way this code is not working.

Comment: My apologies, the sensor is submitting successfully but the nodes are not created. There are no errors being logged.

Comment: Did you add the handler to a webform?

Comment: My handler is not showing up in the list of handlers for the webform.

Comment: Fixed: I wasn't paying attention to the metadata at the start of @WeformHandler, which gives the label of the Handler that will appear in the webform. Now that I've recognised that, it is working!!!